# MySQL fulltext search and sort by relevance + TIME

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to show "related articles" block on my website. For this purpose I use the following query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('search string') AS score 
FROM news_items 
WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('search string') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4
```

However, it often shows me very old articles while I want to show the latest ones so I fixed my query as following:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('search string') AS score 
FROM news_items 
WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('search string') > 4 
ORDER BY ctime DESC, score DESC LIMIT 4
```

But in this case I can't get most relevant articles :(

Any ideas on how to find MOST RELEVANT AND FRESH article at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both of your queries are the same.

Comment: true - but you know what he's getting at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change to an aggregate score... something like this:

---

```
SELECT *, 
  (
    MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('search string')
    - 
    (ABS(DATEDIFF(`timestampfield`, NOW())) / 365)
  ) AS score 
FROM news_items 
WHERE 
  MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('search string') > 4 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4
```

In that there's one kinda funky addition, which you'd want to clean up:

```
- (ABS(DATEDIFF(`timestampfield`, NOW())) / 365)
```

This is your `age` component of the score... currently scaled by `<year> = 1 point`

To get that, we start by getting the number of days between the timestamp field and now (absolute value):

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(`timestampfield`, NOW()))
```

Then we scale...

I decided you probably didn't want to loose score based on number of days, because if something was 30 days old it would be -30... seems too harsh. So I chose years... if you want to scale on number of weeks, divide by `52` instead of `365`... and so forth.

This scaling factor will be how you control value between scoring matching and age.

So it ends up being something like: `<match score> - <yearsAgo>`

---

If you do that:

1. 5 (match score) - 0.1 (<1 year ago) = 4.9 *(ok match, but newest)*
2. 5 (match score) - 0.01 (<1 year ago) = 4.99
3. 5 (match score) - 1 (1 year ago) = 4
4. 6 (match score) - 2 (2 years ago) = 4
5. 9 (match score) - 5 (5 years ago) = 4 *(best match, but old)*
6. 7 (match score) - 10 (10 years ago) = -3

---

NOTE this assumes your timestamp field is a full date-time field... if otherwise, you will need to re-cast to a date, or the logic to manipulate the unix timestamp directly.

And here's a debugging version of the query:

```
SELECT
    `created`,
    MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('awesome') as match_score,
    (ABS(DATEDIFF(`created`, NOW())) / 365) as years_ago,
  (
    MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('awesome')
    - 
    (ABS(DATEDIFF(`created`, NOW())) / 365)
  ) AS score 
FROM news_items 
WHERE 
  MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('awesome') > 4 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: OK, if I delete ">4" then I can get the result. However, this query gives me OLDEST articles while I need newest. Here is the result without your solution -- http://clip2net.com/s/3cQ1F0u, here is using your solution -- http://clip2net.com/s/3cQ22cG As you can see it gives totally different results but what is most important it gives me the oldest articles I have in DB, not newest ones.

Comment: The funniest thing is that if MATCH...AGAINST gives me 12 points and ABS(DATEDIFF()) gives me 1 point the result is like 2.5, not 11. O_o

Comment: It looks like your `timestamp` field is not a date, but instead a unix epoch... either cast it as a date, or just manipulate it's value directly.

http://puu.sh/g53Ww/a5a1eb4fce.png

I've edited my answer with a debugging version of the query...